# First time applescript coding issues

Tags: applescript

Alright, so admittedly, I have no idea what I'm doing. I borrowed a lot of code from a script I downloaded. I'm trying to figure out what exactly is wrong with my code. At first, it wouldn't compile and then I tricked into finally doing that (basically by deleting anything that it said was an error)

Now, more than 2/3 of my code is greyed out and won't work. so without further ado- here it is:

```
property progress_factor : 200
property separator : "-"
tell application "iTunes"

    display dialog "\"Create Artist Folder\"

    set lib to library playlist 1
    set numAllTracks to (get count of lib's file tracks)
    set everyPlaylist to (get name of every user playlist)

    set the count to 0

    set ofi to fixed indexing
    set fixed indexing to true

    try
        with timeout of 300000 seconds
            repeat with i from 1 to numAllTracks

                set thisTrack to (get a reference to file track i of lib)

                tell this Track to set {art, alb, dbid} to {get Artist as string, get database ID}

                if (art is not) then
                    set new_playlist_name to (art) as text
                else if
                    set new_playlist_name to " * "
                end if

                --make new playlist if it doesn't exist
                if everyPlaylist does not contain (new_playlist_name as text) then
                    set newPlaylist to (make playlist with properties {name:new_playlist_name})
                    set end of everyPlaylist to new_playlist_name
                end if
            -- Cycle through playlists of main library
                set thisPlaylist to (get a reference to file playlist i of lib)

            -- get Playlist properties
                tell thisPlaylist to set {art} to {get artist as string, get database ID} 

            -- Folder Playlist to put Playlist
                if (art is not) then
                    set new_folderplaylist_name to (art) as text
                else if
                    set new_FolderPlaylits_name to " * various or unnamed

    -- make new Folder Playlist if it doesn't exist
    if everyFolderPlaylist does not contain (new_folderplaylist_name as text) then
        set newFolderPlaylist to (make FolderPlaylist with properties {name:new_folderplaylist_name})
    end if
    set thecount to thecount + 1


    set fixed indexing to ofi
    if frontmost then
        if gave up of (display dialog "Done" buttons {"Yay!"} ¬
            default button 1 with icon 1 giving up after 300) then error number -128
    end if
end tell
```

I really appreciate every bit of help. I also realize this isn't an entirely necessary function in the new iTunes, but I really wanted to write my own.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the script? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
property progress_factor : 200
property separator : "-"
tell application "iTunes"

    display dialog "Create Artist Folder"

    set lib to library playlist 1
    set numAllTracks to (get count of lib's file tracks)
    set everyPlaylist to (get name of every user playlist)

    set the count to 0

    set ofi to fixed indexing
    set fixed indexing to true

    try
        with timeout of 300000 seconds
            repeat with i from 1 to numAllTracks

                set thisTrack to (get a reference to file track i of lib)

                tell thisTrack to set {art, alb, dbid} to {get artist as string, get database ID}

                if (art is not "") then
                    set new_playlist_name to (art) as text
                else
                    set new_playlist_name to " * "
                end if

                --make new playlist if it doesn't exist
                if everyPlaylist does not contain (new_playlist_name as text) then
                    set newPlaylist to (make playlist with properties {name:new_playlist_name})
                    set end of everyPlaylist to new_playlist_name
                end if
                -- Cycle through playlists of main library
                set thisPlaylist to (get a reference to file playlist i of lib)

                -- get Playlist properties
                tell thisPlaylist to set {art} to {get artist as string, get database ID}

                -- Folder Playlist to put Playlist
                if (art is not "") then
                    set new_folderplaylist_name to (art) as text
                else
                    set new_FolderPlaylits_name to " * "
                end if
            end repeat
        end timeout
    end try

    -- make new Folder Playlist if it doesn't exist
    if everyFolderPlaylist does not contain (new_folderplaylist_name as text) then
        set newFolderPlaylist to (make FolderPlaylist with properties {name:new_folderplaylist_name})
    end if
    set thecount to thecount + 1


    set fixed indexing to ofi
    if frontmost then
        if gave up of (display dialog "Done" buttons {"Yay!"} ¬
            default button 1 with icon 1 giving up after 300) then error number -128
    end if
end tell
```

Long story short, you forgot to put in a bunch of `end` statements, and you missed a couple closing quotes.